# Need help in connecting 2 separate networks

Tags: home-networking

I am a farmer and a user and NOT an IT person so I hope you can help me.
**What I have**: 1. A home network (192.168.1.1) connected to the internet.  2. A remote network (192.168.2.1) in my barn connected to IP type cameras.  This remote network has been in place for some time and does have a PC attached to access the cameras.  Wifi works but very cumbersome.
**What I need**: Assuming this is possible, A direct connection between the 2 networks so that users on the home network can access the cameras on the remote network.
I can follow instructions so, if possible, give me the detailed procedures with examples on how to make this connection.  If another router or component is needed let me know the additional setup procedures.  I will run a 100' ethernet cable out to the barn.
Thanks so much for your help.
Jim....

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Put a decent router in the barn.   Hook up a LAN port on this router to the Ethernet line. Hook the other end of the Ethernet to a LAN port on the home network.  Give the barn router a Static IP address on the home network. Turn DHCP OFF on the barn router. Now everything is on one network and Home can talk to Barn equipment

Comment: so do you WANT to have two networks, or would one be sufficient? it's far easier to do it that way, as John suggests.

Comment: My grandson said I should have put down the type of routers..  They both are Netgear Nighthawk R7000.  We had determined earlier with a single network that the data from the cameras was way too much for a single network.  We must keep the busy camera network by itself.....

Comment: Thanks from John on the solution. I'm not sure I can accomplish what you ask but maybe with my 15 year old grandson we can get it done.

Comment: I missed John's comment on making it one network.  No, we need to keep it at 2.  I asked another friend who has some experience in networks and he said that what I want to do will probably not work.  He said you can connect the two separate networks but can only go from the remote back to the main network.  If that is true then I guess I will just leave it the way it is for now.

Comment: I gave you a full answer to make two networks and have good service in the barn

Comment: This won't be that hard, no worries there. when you get stuck, just reach out to us again. you basically have two gross options, collapse the devices into a single network (connecting the devices in parallel), or continue to use two networks, and connect them in series, one connecting into the other. of the two, the single network is simplest and requires the least configuration/management, but both involve you running the cable to the barn. the difference between the two is which ports its connected to in the barn. in the meantime, ask us the questions you need answers to.

Comment: also, I  hear that you are concerned with the data from the cameras. it does depend on what you are doing with them, but traffic from the cameras would not normally saturate the network. older networks using hubs could be overwhelmed by the traffic of one system, but in the modern era, switches will send traffic out only the ports that the destination is on, so they handle continuous data flows rather well.

Comment: An IT Tech from the local college called me yesterday with the answer I was looking for.  It still uses the existing routers but adds another router using the ER-605 unit.  He said you connect the whole thing via the LAN ports on all 3 routers.  I'm busy with work right now but will attempt to try this out as soon as the new router arrives.

Answer (score 0):

You want two networks and better (faster Wireless).

Get a decent router for the barn.

Connect the WAN port on the new router to the Ethernet.

Connect the Ethernet to the main House Network.

The House is 192.168.1.x  so you can set up the new Router at 192.168.2.x as you have now.  Set this up in the LAN administration section of the new router.

Ethernet for 100 feet should have good performance (as fast as the House).

The new router for the barn can be a Wireless router and give you good wireless in the barn.

What you want can be readily accomplished.

Comment: John that is exactly what we ended up doing but of course that only allows connection from the barn to the house.  We got the new 3rd modem and the tech from the college could not get it to work so we sent it back.  So with the new 100' run to the barn and connected as described at least we have internet access at the barn.  We ultimately fond another pc for the house and just use it in WiFi mode connected to the cameras at the barn.  Signal is a little weak but it works good enough.  So we are through messing with this network - - back to farming!

Comment: You might wish to acknowledge / accept my answer for the work I did

Comment: I acknowledge the answer you gave me on the alternate setup.  That connection method is all over the network and the IT tech set that up before he left.  The fact remains though that my original request for connection between the two separate networks so I had access both ways was never answered.   Thanks anyway for your response.